# Whats the programmatic opposite of showViewController:sender:

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I'm writing an iOS 8 only app and I'm using the new adaptive presentations using a combination of the "Show" and the "Show Detail" segue and the `showViewController:sender:` and `showDetailViewController:sender:` methods.

My question is what is the programatic way to go back after calling `showViewController:sender:`? The way the view controller is shown depends on its parent context. E.g. in a `UINavigationController` `showViewController:sender:` pushes a new controller onto the navigation stack but if there is no UIKit container in the view controller graph then `showViewController:sender:` ends up doing a presentation instead.

Considering i could write my own arbitrary container controller it seems unfeasible to check

```
if (self.navigationController) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else if (self.presentingViewController){
...
else if ([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[CrazyCustomContainer class]]){
    [self.parentViewController someWackyUnwindMethod];
}
...
```

etc... so is there a generic way to reverse being shown? If not the only solution i see is to use unwind segues for everything. Not too much of a hassle but I'm curious.

Comment: I think part of that is because with a model you'd have a cancel button and call the normal `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` and with a navigationController it would have a built in back button. So you don't often have to handle dismissals the same way your handle presentations.

Comment: But thats my point: `showViewController:` can do either a push or a presentation. The presented view controller shouldn't know how it was displayed on screen so doing something like `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]` in the presented isn't good if it can sometimes fail because you were presented...

Comment: Well for a navController you wouldnt need to pop. It would have a back.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a chapter on how `showViewController:sender:` and `showDetailViewController:sender:` work in [Programming iOS 8: Dive Deep into Views, View Controllers, and Frameworks](https://books.google.ru/books?id=wLaVBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT599&dq=%22showDetailViewController%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=IprGVL6FBIGeywOwxoGQBA&ved=0CCQQuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=%22showDetailViewController%22&f=false).

When these methods are called, they call `targetViewControllerForAction:sender:` on themselves and call this method on the returned object. The target object can then display the view controller in an appropriate way. For example, a navigation controller pushes the view controller on its navigation stack.

So you can create a generic `dismissVC:` method and override it in different `UIViewController` subclasses.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func dismissVC(sender:AnyObject?) {
        if let presentingVC = targetViewControllerForAction("dismissVC", withSender: sender) as? UIViewController {
            presentingVC.dismissVC(self)
        }
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    override func dismissVC(sender: AnyObject?) {
        popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

extension CrazyCustomContainer {
    override func dismissVC(sender: AnyObject?) {
        someWackyUnwindMethod()
    }
}
```

This way, when you call `dismissVC:` method, if will always correctly dismiss the view controller depending on the context.

Comment: So, based on this, the actual answer to the question "Is there a programmatic opposite to `showViewController:sender:`?" is **no**. You must effectively implement your own generic version using the same underlying mechanism that Apple uses to do the adaptive presentation.

Comment: Yup thats the case. Although in the question I'm kinda looking for a programmatic alternative to unwind segues, which also need code to support them. This answer 100% fulfils what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I've used before showViewController existed that may help.

```
if let nav = navigationController {
    // We have a navigation controller so we'll have a back button
}
else {
    // no navigation controller, need a cancel button
    // ... Add Cancel Button
}
```

Basically you check for where you're at. Then after that you can put any save code in `viewDidDisappear` or something like that for it work for both. Another option is to check for `presentationViewController` but this doesn't always guarantee modal presentation.