# UIStoryboard Show (e.g. push) simple inverse action to go back

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard, xcode6.1

In storyboard we have great feature that allow us to make Show (e.g. push). So seems the logic is next:

If we don't have navigation controller then view controller will use present modal logic. My question is there any inverse action that I can use with Show?

I have a UIButton that close current view controller screen:

```
- (IBAction)onTappedCloseButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But in case if I don't have navigation controller, how can I simple use inverse action to go back? So my solution is to check if self.navigationController is nil then use dismissing option:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But maybe there is another cool solution like Show (e.g push). But Close (e.g. pop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an unwind segue to go back, and it will be the reverse of whatever the forward segue was.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options on how to do this:

1) The Unwind segue

To make an unwind segue you have to add a method in the view controller you want to "unwind" to with the following format:

`-(IBAction)someSelectorName:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender;`

You will then be able to drag from your UIButton up to the "exit" icon in your storyboard.

[image]

Wire it up to the selector you just defined and UIKit will figure out how to get back to that view controller without you having to write any code. This can be especially useful as it can figure out when it needs to call `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:` more than once and can call those methods successfully. It can even unwind from within a view controller embedded in a navigation controller when the view controller you're unwinding to has the navigation controller presented on top of it. (i.e. it will do a dismissViewController instead of a pop to unwind)

2) The Custom unwind method

Say you don't want to or cant trigger this action from a storyboard. There is still an option and its detailed over at this question here:

[Whats the programmatic opposite of showViewController:sender:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742944/whats-the-programmatic-opposite-of-showviewcontrollersender)

The gist is you can write your own generic dismiss method by implementing categories on the UIKit container View controllers (or on your own container)